# Rate of mixing of two regions containing particles undergoing Brownian motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Suppose the plane is densely populated with particles at a density of $\delta_0$ per unit area, except for in a bounded region $\Omega$, in which there are none.

Suppose the particles move according to Brownian motion, and that they may wander into $\Omega$ through a small opening $\ell$ in the boundary of $\Omega$. See my diagram:

[image]

How does the density of $\Omega$ change over time? I know that as $t\to\infty$, the density of $\Omega$ approaches $\delta_0$. I suspect that the rate of convergence to $\delta_0$ is determined by the length of $\ell$, and also by the parameters of the random motion.

My question is: what is an expression for the density of $\Omega$ at a given time $t\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: I don't have the background to actually answer you, but this looks a _lot_ like a simple heat equation $$u_t = \alpha \Delta u$$ with the boundary condition $$x \in \delta \Omega \setminus \ell \implies u(x,t) = 0 \\ x \in \ell \implies u(x,t) = \delta_0 \\ x\in \Omega \implies u(x,0) = 0$$
Have you already investigated it this way?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I knew it had something to do with heat equation. Although I don't think this generalizes well to my real problems, which have multiple regions, this completely answers my question. I will mark it as answered unless someone else posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $l$ sufficiently smaller compared to the circumference of $\Omega$, you could try this simple approach.

Assume that after the "animals" enter the $\Omega$ area, they *instantaneously* distribute evenly in $\Omega$. Let $x, y$ denotes the density of the animal outside and inside of $\Omega$, respectively. Then what we want to find is: $\frac{dy}{dt}$.

Because the plane is densely populated with the animals at a fixed density of $\delta_0$, you can just consider the area immediately surrounding the opening of length $l$.
Since the animal is moving via diffusion and we assume that once entering $\Omega$, the animals distribute evenly, then the amount of animal entering the region $\Omega$ is proportional to the diffusive rate times the difference in density of the two regions. This gives:
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} = c(x-y)l = cl(\delta_0 - y).
$$
As you can see, for $t$ approaches $\infty$, $y$ also approaches $\delta_0$.

I do not know how realistic you would like your system to be, but this a simple way of modeling this system.

Comment: This is the basic insight I was hoping to achieve, thank you. It seems like your approach is a sort of "linear approximation", where we assume $\Omega$ is rather convex and $\ell$ is rather straight. However I still wonder about the diffusive rate $c$, how is that related to the random motion? For example, what is $c$ if the particles use Brownian motion?

Comment: @M.Nestor The diffusive constant $c$ needs to be derived case by case. Its interpretation also depends on the specific application. For instance, you can find on page 405 of "Mathematical Models in Biology" by Leah Edelstein-Keshet (should be online somewhere) that in the simple 1-D case, $c$ is the fixed limit of $(\Delta x)^2/2\tau$ as $\tau\rightarrow 0$ and $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$. Here, $\Delta x, \tau$ are the movement distance and the time unit, respectively. Additionally, the work from Akira Okubo on diffusion in ecology may contain the information that you want.